# What is the best resource for learning (N)ASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've been wanting to learn assembly for a while now, and although I've tried a few times before, I haven't really been able to get past "Hello, world". Are there any good introductory tutorials to assembly (preferably using NASM, as I use Windows and Linux)?

I do have a bit of C knowledge, but mainly code in higher-level languages such as Ruby, Python, C# and JavaScript.

Comment: There are some good links to guides for learning x86 asm in general in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  It sounds like you're asking more about x86 asm in general than NASM syntax / macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my Assembly language class, we're using the book that [Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421631/what-is-the-best-resource-for-learning-nasm#421676) recommends.  My professor also recommended this book: [Assembly Language Step-by-step: Programming with DOS and Linux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471375233).  He said that this is the only book that he knows of that covers NASM (and it's a tad outdated).

Comment: That's in this question.  :-)

Comment: I just figured that out - I had another tab open with a different question :)

Answer (score 10):

Here's an interesting page from a former teacher. http://drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/

I haven't read through his online book, though.

Comment: This is the book that we're using for my assembly language class.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried a few assemblers, and I found [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) is the most beginner-friendly. It has a somewhat bad macro language, but otherwise it is an excellent piece of software. It supports both Windows and Linux object formats (either 32 or 64 bit). It has an active and good community, and plenty of beginner-friendly examples.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there are not so many good resources and books to learn `nasm`. But some of them I could recommend:

**Resources**:

- Of course [official NASM documentation](https://www.nasm.us/doc/)
- [Low-Level Programming: C, Assembly, and Program Execution on Intel ® 64 Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484224027)
- [Assembly Language for Intel-Based Computers(Kip R. Irvine)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132383101)
- [Introduction to 64 Bit Intel Assembly Language Programming for Linux(Benjamin Ray Seyfarth)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1478119209)
- SO's x86 tag wiki, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has links to tutorials, manuals, and performance-tuning info.

This list will be updated as soon as I find new good resources.

Answer (score -3):

Not specifically for NASM, but [The MASM Forum](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?) has a lot of great information, and you will get more assistance if you ask your question their.