# NASM - Relative Include Files

Tags: include, nasm, assembly

I want to include some files in the parent or sub directory of my source files. Is it possible with NASM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good NASM/FASM tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947121/a-good-nasm-fasm-tutorial)

Comment: I'm not trying to learn assembler. I'm just using an other assembler most of the time and can't find a way to include a file located in a relative directory without using the "-i" command line parameter in NASM.

Answer (score 3):

NASM has several ways how to include one file in another.

1. `%include` directive:

Which works similar to `#include` directive in `C`, e.g. you can write relative paths like so `%include "some_dir/awesome.asm"`. If you don't want to specify relative paths to your files every time in the source code, you can determinate include file search directories via [-i option](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.17)

After preprocessing the actual output can be seen using [-E option](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.21).

2. Pre-Include a File(quote from [the docs](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.18)):

> NASM allows you to specify files to be pre-included into your source
>   file, by the use of the `-p` option.
>
> `nasm myfile.asm -p myinc.inc` is equivalent to running `nasm myfile.asm`
>   and placing the directive `%include "myinc.inc"` at the start of the
>   file.